# Is it reliable to call GetLastError() after a failed HeapAlloc()?

Tags: windows, winapi

I was looking at some code recently that did call `GetLastError()` after `HeapAlloc()` had failed. But, according to the [HeapAlloc function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) MSDN docs:

> If the function fails, it does not call SetLastError. An application cannot call GetLastError for extended error information.

The Internet is littered with code snippets that are calling `GetLastError()` after a failed `HeapAlloc()`, and I assume most coders (including myself) are programmed to naturally call `GetLastError()` when an API fails.

To test, I created this example to allocate the max amount of memory:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
    if (hHeap == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to get the process heap.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    SetLastError(0);  // Clear the last error

    // Attempt to allocate a very large amount of memory
    SIZE_T largeSize = SIZE_MAX;
    LPVOID pMemory = HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, largeSize);

    if (pMemory == NULL) {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        printf("HeapAlloc failed: ");

        switch (dwError) {
        case ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY:
            printf("Not enough memory available.\n");
            break;
        case ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY:
            printf("Insufficient memory to satisfy the request.\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error code: %lu\n", dwError);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Memory allocation successful.\n");
        HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pMemory);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output shows:

> HeapAlloc failed: Not enough memory available.

**Question**

Why does `GetLastError()` appear to work? Is it just luck, so everyone should avoid calling it because relying on `GetLastError()` for detailed error information may not be reliable?

**Update**

The official documentation for `HeapAlloc()` notes:

> If the function fails, it does not call SetLastError. An application cannot call GetLastError for extended error information.

However, from the comments below, the internal implementation of `HeapAlloc()` updates the `LastErrorValue` in the TEB, but is not documented for external developers.

Here's an example of `HeapAlloc` updating `LastErrorValue` in the TEB with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` 8.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <intrin.h>

typedef struct _MY_TEB {
    // The TEB is highly stable across Windows versions.
    uint8_t Padding[0x68];
    ULONG LastErrorValue; 
    // ...
} MY_TEB;

int main() {
    SetLastError(0);
    printf("LastErrorValue (TEB): %lu\n", ((MY_TEB*)__readgsqword(0x30))->LastErrorValue);
    printf("GetLastError (API):   %lu\n", GetLastError());

    HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, SIZE_MAX);
    printf("LastErrorValue (TEB): %lu\n", ((MY_TEB*)__readgsqword(0x30))->LastErrorValue);
    printf("GetLastError (API):   %lu\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
LastErrorValue (TEB): 0
GetLastError (API):   0
LastErrorValue (TEB): 8
GetLastError (API):   8
```

To sum up, I'll stick with the official documentation to NOT call `GetLastError()`. Thanks.

Comment: Two possibilities: (a) that part of the doc used to be true but is no longer or (b) "does not call" should have been changed to "may not call".

Comment: `SetLastError` of course not called ( because HeapAlloc == RtlAllocateHeap in *ntdll.dll*  ) but `RtlAllocateHeap` direct set `LastErrorValue` in `TEB`, if it fail.

Comment: @RbMm Interesting, so does GetLastError() reference the TEB field `LastErrorValue` directly? If so, is calling GetLastError() after a HeapAlloc() failure valid?

Comment: of course  GetLastError() reference the TEB field LastErrorValue directly. but probably not in all windows versions `RtlAllocateHeap` set `LastErrorValue`. `LocalAlloc` is shell over `RtlAllocateHeap`. if it fail - it set hardcoded last error to `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`

Comment: The possible errors are ERROR_SUCCESS, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK, ERROR_HEAP_CORRUPTED, ERROR_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND. So, is it reliable to call GetLastError() or is the msdn doc correct that it should never be called? I'm using win11 pro.

Comment: i be say use GetLastError - depend from windows version. probably in xp/2003 RtlAllocateHeap not set LastErrorValue. in latest version - set. where was change - i not check

Comment: When the documentation says it **does not call SetLasltError()**, that means that it **DOES NOT** call SetLastError(), and therefore GetLastError() provides ZERO information about why it failed. **does not call** can't be stated any more clearly than that, unless the prefaced it with **READ THIS CAREFULLY, BECAUSE WE'RE NOT KIDDING! WE'RE REALLY SERIOUS ABOUT THIS, BECAUSE IT'S A FACT!** Anything you get from GetLastError() is absolutely useless, and calling GetLastError() is just wasted keystrokes and processor time.

Comment: @Ken White `HeapAlloc()` may not call `SetLasltError()` directly but from testing, the TEB is updated with the last error code, so calling `GetLastError()` appears to function as desired. However, if the MSDN doc is up-to-date (sometimes it's not always accurate), then calling `GetLastError()` is ill-advised as you noted.

Comment: The value is meaningless. The documentation hasn't changed since `HealAlloc()` was written, and neither has the function's use. MS has stated from the beginning of the function's existence that it does not SetLastError() on failure, at least as far back as Windows 3.x. You can't use any value you read from GetlastError() after HeapAlloc() fails, because it is not meaningful. If it is documented as not being meaningful because it is never set, then relying on that value to convey anything useful is simply foolish.

Comment: Also, the rules for calling `GetLastError()` are clear - you call `GetLastError()` when a call to an API function fails **and** that function is documented to say that you should use `GetLastError()` upon failure to find out why.

Comment: @KenWhite how minimum from win7 `RtlAllocateHeap` set `LastErrorValue`. documentation too long out of date. another question - not very usefull know error here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To test, [...]

You cannot "test" whether a contract is in effect.

Contracts are.

The combination of preconditions and postconditions is called a *contract*. An *implementation* is entitled to loosen its preconditions and strengthen its postconditions. When that happens, it is called an *implementation detail*.

Implementation details aren't part of the contract.

If the documentation for [`HeapAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) states that

> An application cannot call `GetLastError` for extended error information.

then that is the contract pertaining to its postcondition. Don't call `GetLastError` when `HeapAlloc` returns `NULL`.